# How to clear form control in run time c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm designing a Windows Form to create a child form at run time. I would like that the child form build controls (buttons, list boxes, etc.) depending on a the text entered in the parent form. My problem is when I close the child form, enter new text and relaunch the child form, the same control is being created.

This is how I call the child form:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Form2 frm2 = new Form2();

                frm2.Show();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

This is the code in the child form

```
try
            {
                this.MaximizeBox = false;
                this.MinimizeBox = false;
                this.BackColor = Color.White;
                this.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(550, 550);
                this.Text = "Test Create form in run time ";
               Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
               if (frm1.master == "button")
                  {
                    this.btnAdd.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                    this.btnAdd.Text = "Add";
                    this.btnAdd.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(90, 25);
                    this.btnAdd.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 25);
                    this.Controls.Add(btn);
                }
}
```

Can anyone give me a piece of code or link ?

Comment: add your code, probably you are not destroying the old windows.

Comment: in the OnClose of the form2 make something like this: text.Text = "" in the control having the text

Comment: Are you data binding the form controls from and object structure?

Comment: @ElMarce I'm destroy the old window at every button click to enter the text using `Form1.Close();`

Comment: That won't "destroy" the window. Just close it.

Make something like this

`form2.Dispose();`

`form2 = new Form()`

Comment: put your code so I can have a clear idea of the problem

Comment: @ElMarce updated done

Comment: `Form2 frm1 = new Form1();`
`if (frm1.master == "button")`

Do you realize that frm1 is a newly created form and not the parent form?

Comment: @ElMarce Yes, Sorry for the edit wrong check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not sending the text from From1, instead you are creating a new Form1 inside Form2. This is not what you want I guess...

To solve this:

1. Add a String property in Form2, called say 'ControlText'.
2. Suppose that the user write the text in a text box called Text1 in
   Form1

Then you would call form2 from Form1 like this:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
                frm2.ControlText = Text1.text
                frm2.Show();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Finally, the code in form2 will be something like this:

```
try
            {
                this.MaximizeBox = false;
                this.MinimizeBox = false;
                this.BackColor = Color.White;
                this.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(550, 550);
                this.Text = "Test Create form in run time ";
               if (ControlText == "button")
                  {
                    this.btnAdd.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                    this.btnAdd.Text = "Add";
                    this.btnAdd.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(90, 25);
                    this.btnAdd.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 25);
                    this.Controls.Add(btn);
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this may help you

```
private void Form1_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
  Utilities.ResetAllControls(this);
}

public class Utilities
    {
        public static void ResetAllControls(Control form)
        {
            foreach (Control control in form.Controls)
            {
                if (control is TextBox)
                {
                    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)control;
                    textBox.Text = null;
                }

                if (control is ComboBox)
                {
                    ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)control;
                    if (comboBox.Items.Count > 0)
                        comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }

                if (control is CheckBox)
                {
                    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)control;
                    checkBox.Checked = false;
                }

                if (control is ListBox)
                {
                    ListBox listBox = (ListBox)control;
                    listBox.ClearSelected();
                }
            }
        }      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    foreach(control in this.Controls)
    {
        this.Controls.Remove(control);
        control.Dispose();
    }
    this.Controls.Clear();
```